# Ubuntu 15.04 installation process doesn't load the keyboard layout I gave

Tags: keyboard

**Note:** This behaviour has been seen on Ubuntu Server, but it should be the same with the Desktop version.

On Ubuntu 14.04 Server installation process, if you set the English language, but choose the FR keyboard layout, the FR keyboard layout is loaded for the rest of the installation.

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 Server, and during the installation process, I did the same thing:

- English language
- FR keyboard layout

But the FR keyboard layout is not loaded.

I did it twice to be sure. The fun part is that except my password, all the input I had to give were mapped the same way in the FR/US layout, but when the computer started, bam, wrong password, because I typed it with the US layout during the installation.

**Why does Ubuntu 15.04 Server decided not to load the given keyboard layout?**

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you have bound something to super+space keyboard combination? This is as far as I know the default "switch layout" binding and may be the reason.

It's also possible that you got both layouts when installing which would be fixed by `System settings -> Text entry`

Just delete the US layout and you should be good to go.